# Images displaying as question mark in mobile devices for prestashop version 1.5

Tags: image, mobile, prestashop

Website working fine in all browsers, but the issue is, it is loading webpage in mobile devices but with question mark in all images of the page. is it the problem with image size? if so, then what is the mobile image size need to be set?

Answer (score 0):

It's like you've encountered BOM, you can see here to solve it: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark

Comment: Its not showing the images only in the mobile version. W3C Validation is done already. can you please say from where the mobile theme is function.

Comment: can you help me, how to find the url in mobile version. Two things I dont know. 1. there is no mobile folder inside the theme, from where mobile version functionality works. 2. whether I need to set the image in back end for mobile. kindly help me out in this .

Comment: It's pretty simple: if you are using the relative path for the images like: path/to/your/image.png, and the url of the "pc version" is like: http://yourdomain.com so the browser will look for the image at the directory: your/web/base/path/to/your/image.png, but at the mobile version wich url: http://yourdomain.com/mobile, the browser now will look for the image at: your/web/base/mobile/path/to/your/image.png. So you can change the resource url to absolute path to fix this

Comment: Thanks. The themes takes default mobile theme.. I created the new image property for that and re generated the thumbnails. It displays the images now in the mobile version... Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The themes takes default mobile theme.. The new image property is created for that and re generated the thumbnails. It displays the images now in the mobile version...